# javascript: Can't get setTimeout to work properly

Tags: javascript, loops, timeout, maps, leaflet

I have an array of objects on a map with leaflet.
I'd like my map to pan to every object after some time.

```
var idx = 0;
function getNextPoint(point) {
  console.log(idx);
  map.panTo(new L.LatLng(point.y,point.x), true, 1, 0.5);
  idx++;
  if (idx < points.length) {
    setTimeout(getNextCenter(points[idx]), 4000);
  }
}

setTimeout(getNextPoint(points[idx]), 4000);
```

So I expect this code to execute getNextPoint() after 4s, pan to the first point, then set the next timeout, and execute the method again after 4s etc until the idx max is reached.

But it's not what it's doing. It quickly loops over all points and just only makes one visible pan.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to do something like `setTimeout(getNextPoint(points[idx]), idx * 4000);` or am I wrong?

Comment: The reason is you're executing the function, instead of defining the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your timeout function in another function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    getNextPoint(points[idx]);
}, 4000);
```

Comment: My guess is still `setTimeout...}, idx * 4000);` for the expected behaviour?!?

Comment: I don't really understand this, although I'm happy it works. getNextPoint() is a function call, so I don't understand why I need to wrap it into another function?

Comment: @fablife - because `setTimeout()` takes a function as a parameter. You were passing in the result of a function, not a function itself.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass in the function into setTimeout, don't call it with (). Just put in the name.

```
function print () {
  console.log('hello!')
}
setTimeout(print, 4000);
```

In your case, you also want to pass in additional arguments into getNextPoint. In modern browsers ([look at MDN for compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout#Browser_compatibility)), you can pass them into setTimeout

```
setTimeout(getNextPoint, 4000, points[idx])
```

To support all browsers, you can bind the arguments into the function with [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
setTimeout(getNextPoint.bind(null, points[idx]), 4000)
```